# In-app checkout interface is always in landscape mode on Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, google-play

I'm building application on SKD 11+ (Android 3.x) and when I'm doing in-app billing request the checkout popup is always displaying in landscape mode - causing that my whole app rotates to landscape mode even though the app is locked to portrait!

Is there any way to display purchase popup in portrait mode on Honeycomb? Apparently it has something to do with Android Market which is displaying only in landscape too, as it is responsible for checkout popup.

Thanks.